# Snmpset not working on an agent generated by mib2c

Tags: c, linux, snmp, net-snmp, snmpd

I generated code from MIB file with mib2c. When I try to set object with read-write access, it returns `Error in packet.` `Reason: notWritable (That object does not support modification`.
I tried to run my subagent with few debug flags. I found out that not a single function generated code is called on snmpset request, only on snmpget. smnpget on exactly same OID will return valid value. I have user with RW access everywhere. I can set value to sysName.0 with same user. I tried removing MIB file and use exact oid but had same result.

Because It's not even reaching code, I don't know much what to do.

I tried it with 2 tables generated same way.
One table has index as IMPLIED DisplayString and second table has INDEX as combination of 2 INTEGERs.

**EDIT:**
I found out that it created .conf file in /var/lib/snmp/ for each my agent. I tried to add create_user with same name & password but it disappeared after agent was started again.

**EDIT2:**
Code was generetad using mib2c.mfd.conf . I tried mib2c.iterate.conf and it called function from generated code. It's not working with mib2c.mfd.conf but looks like it will work with mib2c.iterate.conf . I would like to be able make it works with mib2c.mfd.conf so I wouldn't need to change all subagents.

Output from my subagent where 3.fw is index:

```
agentx/subagent: checking status of session 0x44150
agentx_build: packet built okay
agentx/subagent: synching input, op 0x01
agentx/subagent: session 0x44150 responded to ping
agentx/subagent: handling AgentX request (req=0x1f9,trans=0x1f8,sess=0x21)
agentx/subagent:   -> testset
snmp_agent: agent_sesion  0xc4a08 created
snmp_agent: add_vb_to_cache( 0xc4a08, 1, MSE-CONFIGURATION-MIB::mseDpuConfigActivationAdminStatus.3.fw,  0x3d3d0)
snmp_agent: tp->start MSE-CONFIGURATION-MIB::mseDpuConfigActivationTable, tp->end MSE-CONFIGURATION-MIB::mseDpuConfigActivation.3,
agent_set: doing set mode = 0 (SET_RESERVE1)
agent_set: did set mode = 0, status = 17
results: request results (status = 17):
results:        MSE-CONFIGURATION-MIB::mseDpuConfigActivationAdminStatus.3.fw = INTEGER: prepare(1)
snmp_agent: REMOVE session ==  0xc4a08
snmp_agent: agent_session  0xc4a08 released
snmp_agent: end of handle_snmp_packet, asp =  0xc4a08
agentx/subagent: handling agentx subagent set response (mode=162,req=0x1f9,trans=0x1f8,sess=0x21)
agentx_build: packet built okay
agentx/subagent:   FINISHED
agentx/subagent: handling AgentX request (req=0x1fa,trans=0x1f8,sess=0x21)
agentx/subagent:   -> cleanupset
snmp_agent: agent_sesion  0xc7640 created
agent_set: doing set mode = 4 (SET_FREE)
agent_set: did set mode = 4, status = 17
results: request results (status = 17):
results:        MSE-CONFIGURATION-MIB::mseDpuConfigActivationAdminStatus.3.fw = INTEGER: prepare(1)
snmp_agent: REMOVE session ==  0xc7640
snmp_agent: agent_session  0xc7640 released
snmp_agent: end of handle_snmp_packet, asp =  0xc7640
agentx/subagent: handling agentx subagent set response (mode=162,req=0x1fa,trans=0x1f8,sess=0x21)
agentx_build: packet built okay
agentx/subagent:   FINISHED
agentx/subagent: checking status of session 0x44150
agentx_build: packet built okay
agentx/subagent: synching input, op 0x01
agentx/subagent: session 0x44150 responded to ping
```

Values/config used for generating code:

```
## defaults
@eval $m2c_context_reg = "netsnmp_data_list"@
@eval $m2c_data_allocate = 0@
@eval $m2c_data_cache = 1@
@eval $m2c_data_context = "generated"@ [generated|NAME]
@eval $m2c_data_init = 1@
@eval $m2c_data_transient = 0@
@eval $m2c_include_examples = 1@
@eval $m2c_irreversible_commit = 0@
@eval $m2c_table_access = "container-cached"@
@eval $m2c_table_dependencies = 0@
@eval $m2c_table_persistent = 0@
@eval $m2c_table_row_creation = 0@
@eval $m2c_table_settable = 1@
@eval $m2c_table_skip_mapping = 1@
@eval $m2c_table_sparse = 1@
@eval $mfd_generate_makefile = 1@
@eval $mfd_generate_subagent = 1@
```

SNMPd version:

```sh
# snmpd --version
NET-SNMP version:  5.9
Web:               http://www.net-snmp.org/
Email:             net-snmp-coders@lists.sourceforge.net
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that in generated file *_interface.c from mib2c.mfd.conf template, there is inverted check.

```c
#if !(defined(NETSNMP_NO_WRITE_SUPPORT) || defined(NETSNMP_DISABLE_SET_SUPPORT))
                                                      HANDLER_CAN_RONLY
#else
                                                      HANDLER_CAN_RWRITE
#endif /* NETSNMP_NO_WRITE_SUPPORT || NETSNMP_DISABLE_SET_SUPPORT */
```

**I removed ! from condition** and it stared working. Both defines are undefined so it should use HANDLER_CAN_RWRITE but because of wrong check it used HANDLER_CAN_RONLY.

Comment: 5 years old bug and still present :(  
 https://net-snmp-coders.narkive.com/2HhRCxph/how-to-enable-set-support-in-snmpd-for-mibs#post3