# Snmpset command is not changing oid content

Tags: snmp, mib, oid

I want to change the content of an oid I want using the snmpset command:

```
snmpget -v 2c -c public 10.1.240.53 .1.3.6.1.4.1.1023.1.2.1.2.1.3.1

output->SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1023.1.2.1.2.1.3.1 = INTEGER: 1
```

So to change the content, ı used:

```
snmpset -v 2c -c public 10.1.240.53 .1.3.6.1.4.1.1023.1.2.1.2.1.3.1 integer 9

output->SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1023.1.2.1.2.1.3.1 = INTEGER: 9
```

But when ı write this command again

```
snmpget -v 2c -c public 10.1.240.53 .1.3.6.1.4.1.1023.1.2.1.2.1.3.1

SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.1023.1.2.1.2.1.3.1 = INTEGER: 1
```

The content is not changing.

Comment: Does this help?:  [Snmpset not working on an agent generated by mib2c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69163493/snmpset-not-working-on-an-agent-generated-by-mib2c) ??

Comment: no this is different topic

Comment: `public` is usually read-only. Check the configuration for a community string with write access

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the object you're trying to alter using SNMPSET is read-only and cannot be changed. As far as I can tell it is INTELSAL enterprise specific MIB file. So you need to check private MIB files/

Comment: I wrote a script to change the value of the object. The script I wrote is read-only. i fixed it and it worked.Thank you very much. This answer helped me a lot